# Converting a string representation to a date with XSLT

Tags: xslt, jira

Based on the XML RSS feed from JIRA I'm trying to create some grouping based on the date - i.e. how many bugs within one month throughout the year.
This is giving me some problems. I can find and group the tasks based on their type, but when it comes to handling the date I have come short.

The date string look like this: `<created>Thu, 4 Oct 2012 10:53:38 +0200</created>`.
My problem is that I cannot seem to extract the month and year from this string.

The script are to run under JIRA/Confluence, so I doubt that the date-paser from exslt will work on that platform.

I do not need the time, so that can be removed. What I need is to be able extract the month + year from this text string in order for me to group by those (02-2012).

Comment: Grouping should be possible with concat of some substring-after and substring-before calls, to get OCT-2012. But your problem than may be sorting.

Comment: *"The date string looks like this `Thu, 4 Oct 2012 10:53:38 +0200`"* - And that's the problem right there. Why in the name of all that's holy do people use this entirely brain-dead date format? (Ranting, I'm sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

Quite an ugly but still an grouping issue. The "normal" solution with xslt-1.0 is **muenchian grouping** (e.g look to [this](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)).

With this key:

```
<xsl:key name="kMonthYear" match="created"  use="concat( 
                        substring-before(
                            substring-after( substring-after( substring-after(., ' '), ' '),' ')
                            , ' '),
                         '-', 
                         substring-before(
                            substring-after( substring-after(., ' '), ' ')
                            , ' ')
                        )" />
```

Loop over group:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//created[
         generate-id() = generate-id(key('kMonthYear', concat( 
                    substring-before(
                        substring-after( substring-after( substring-after(., ' '), ' '),' ')
                        , ' '), 
                     '-', 
                     substring-before(
                        substring-after( substring-after(., ' '), ' ')
                        , ' ')
                    ))[1])
          ]" >
```

Loop over group members

```
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kMonthYear', concat( 
                    substring-before(
                        substring-after( substring-after( substring-after(., ' '), ' '),' ')
                        , ' '), 
                     '-', 
                     substring-before(
                        substring-after( substring-after(., ' '), ' ')
                        , ' ')
                    ))" >
```

I do not see how to sort by month, without any extension or with xslt-2.0, but this was not requested.

Comment: Hehe, yes not that pretty.
I'll give it a go. Thanks!